# Switching databases at runtime in Mongoid 3.0

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have a Sinatra application running on Unicorn that uses Mongoid for its models. I have several Mongo databases with the same structure but different content, and I to select the right database for each user when he/she logs in. I am wondering if this is possible with Mongoid 3.0.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to switch database, use `Mongoid.override_database`, it's Thread safe.

`Mongoid.override_database("client_db_name") # change the database`
`Mongoid.override_database(nil) # reset the database`

Example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :switch_database
  after_filter :reset_database

  private

  def switch_database
    client_ref = params[:client_id]
    Mongoid.override_database("my_db_name_#{client_ref}")
  end

  def reset_database
    Mongoid.override_database(nil)
  end
end
```

Documentation can be found [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html#custom).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `with` operator before every query:

```
Model.with(database: method_to_get_the_db_name).create
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the [mongoid-dynamic-clients](https://github.com/pavlo/mongoid-dynamic-clients) gem.

Also I have my own helper method for Mongoid 5 which uses the default connection but different database name:

```
  def within_database(name)
    previous_client = Mongoid::Threaded.client_override
    unless Mongoid::Config.clients[name].present?
      Mongoid.clients[name] = Mongoid::Config.clients[:default].dup
      Mongoid.clients[name][:database] = name
      Mongoid::Config.clients[name][:__instance] = Mongoid::Clients::Factory::create(name)
    end

    Mongoid.override_client(name)

    yield Mongoid::Config.clients[name][:__instance]

    Mongoid.override_client(previous_client)
  end
```

Usage:

```
within_database('my_different_database') do |connection|
  puts "Current database: #{connection.database.name}"
  Model.all.length
  # Or you may even drop it by using the connection object
  connection.database.drop
end
```